# Pass multiple objects from servlet to Javascript file using ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

In my login servlet page have some conditions.The user is registered user pass URL to JavaScript using ajax call. If the user is not registered then try to login i need to display error message and redirect to same page URL but here i am unable to pass both URL and message at a time to JavaScript file using ajax call i am able to pass only one object either URL or  message anyone please tell me how to pass both objects to JavaScript.

Comment: Appologies - i misunderstood your question please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the Strings of URL and MSG and pass in out.println with a delimiter and then split the same at other end in JS.

```
  if
  {
      data ="Login.jsp$Sorry, you are not a registered user! Please sign up 
      first";
   }
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.print(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens Because `print(arg)` of Class **PrintWriter** that you referred by `out` only accepts one single argument. be it of any type. view API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). Assuming that you always get a success callback. 
try should work:

code:

```
String resp= "";    // final response
if(User.isValid())
{                  
    resp="MyList.jsp" ;
}
else
{
    Url="Login.jsp";
    Msg="Sorry, you are not a registered user! Please sign up first";
    resp= Url + "@" + Msg;
}
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(resp); // based upon your condition above.
```

change your JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnLogin').click(function ()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "Login", //this is my servlet
                data: "uname=" +$('#inputUserID').val()+"&pwd="+$('#inputPassword').val(),

                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    var response = data.split("@");
                    if(response.length>1){
                        // if user is a valid user
                        $(window.location).attr('href', response[0]);
                    } else {
                        // if user in invalid
                        $(window.location).attr('href', response[0]);
                        $("#message").html(response[1]);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I updated my question could you please see once and let me know thank you

Comment: I tried with your instructions but it not displaying message